# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render React issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux

I've re edited the question as it was not relevant... I got an issue in appearing in my browser when I launch my app, this issue is:

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

I've look all over the internet, but still don't manage to make it work.
Here is my code:

```
const DefaultValue = () => {
    let matchingOption = options.find((option) => option.value.includes(countryLabel))
    let optionSelected = options.find((option) => option.value === value)
  
    const hasCountryLabelChanged = countryHasChanged(countryLabel)
    const [selectedPathway, changeSelectedPathway] = useState(matchingOption)

useEffect(() => {
      if (hasCountryLabelChanged) {
        if(matchingOption) {
          changeSelectedPathway(matchingOption)
        } else {
          changeSelectedPathway(options[0])
        }
      } else {
       changeSelectedPathway(optionSelected)
      }

    },[matchingOption, optionSelected, selectedPathway, hasCountryLabelChanged])

    if(selectedPathway !== undefined) {
      const newLevers = levers.map((lever, index) => {
          lever.value = +pathways[selectedPathway.value][index].toFixed(1) * 10
          return lever
      })
      dispatch(Actions.updateAllLevers(newLevers))
    }

     return selectedPathway
  }
  
  const countryHasChanged = (countryLabel) => {
    const prevValue = UsePrevious(countryLabel)
    return prevValue !== countryLabel
  }
  
  const UsePrevious = (countryLabel) => {
    const ref = useRef()
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = countryLabel
    })
    return ref.current
  }
```

the "selectedPathway" is shown in **< select value={DefaultValue} />**

Answer (score 0):

Your `optionValueCheck` call should happen inside a `useEffect` with one of the dependency params as countryLabel. So that whenever countryLabel updates, your function is executed.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message, so the useEffect should be called in the value section? Because when I do that, I get an error message saying that "React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?"